# Scala brackets java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, stack-overflow

I am having trouble with this silly recursive code. It throws StackOverflowError error where it should not, or so I believe. I look through byte code and found the problem.

Could someone explain to me what Scala is doing under the hood?

JVM and Scala version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01-451, mixed mode)

$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.3 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

Here is the small program:

```
package objsets

class Recur(layer: Int, value: Int) {
  def inner = new Recur(layer - 1, value + 1)
  def getVal: Int = {
    if (layer <= 0) value
    else  // if surrond these 2 expressions with brackets, error will go away
      //{  
        print("");   
        inner.getVal
      //}
  }
}

object Recur {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println((new Recur(0, 5)).getVal) // throw java.lang.StackOverflowError
  }
}
```

I tried to look through the compiled byte code and this is what I found.

Without brackets:

```
public int getVal();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield    #25; //Field layer:I
   4:   iconst_0
   5:   if_icmpgt   18
   8:   aload_0
   9:   getfield    #27; //Field value:I
   12:  invokestatic    #41; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   15:  goto    29    // not sure why it goes to 29
   18:  getstatic   #46; //Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
   21:  ldc #48; //String
   23:  invokevirtual   #52; //Method scala/Predef$.print:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   26:  getstatic   #58; //Field scala/runtime/BoxedUnit.UNIT:Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;
   29:  pop
   30:  aload_0
   31:  invokevirtual   #60; //Method inner:()Lobjsets/Recur;
   34:  invokevirtual   #62; //Method getVal:()I
   37:  ireturn
```

With brackets:

```
public int getVal();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield    #25; //Field layer:I
   4:   iconst_0
   5:   if_icmpgt   15
   8:   aload_0
   9:   getfield    #27; //Field value:I
   12:  goto    30
   15:  getstatic   #40; //Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
   18:  ldc #42; //String
   20:  invokevirtual   #46; //Method scala/Predef$.print:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   23:  aload_0
   24:  invokevirtual   #48; //Method inner:()Lobjsets/Recur;
   27:  invokevirtual   #50; //Method getVal:()I
   30:  ireturn
```

It seems the problem is with the "goto 29" in the without brackets version.

Could someone explain to me what Scala is doing under the hood? Is this because Scala trying to figure out the value type of (print("");inner.getVal), but it could not do that at compilation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without brackets your code is equivalent to :

```
class Recur(layer: Int, value: Int) {
  def inner = new Recur(layer - 1, value + 1)
  def getVal: Int = {
    if (layer <= 0) value else print("")  
    return inner.getVal // added explicit return
  }
}
```

Scala always return the last statement in a block, which here is `inner.getVal` (and causes the stack overflow error). The `if (layer <= 0) value` part doesn't return anything.

When you add brackets, you get this :

```
class Recur(layer: Int, value: Int) {
  def inner = new Recur(layer - 1, value + 1)
  def getVal: Int = {
    return (if (layer <= 0) value
            else {  
              print("");   
              inner.getVal
            }
    )
  }
}
```

where when `layer <= 0`, you return value.

Answer (score 1):

If your else block contains multiple statements, you need to surround those statements with brackets, otherwise the print statement is the only thing in the else block, and your `getVal` method will always return `inner.getVal`.